# Checking instances attributes based on list length and indexing

Tags: python, oop, indexing, comparison

I'm looking for a pythonic way to write the same code below but in fewer lines:

```
mylist = [Instance1(), Instance2(), Instance3()]

if mylist[0].skill == 'java' and mylist[0].is_eligible:
    [...]
elif mylist[1].skill == 'java' and mylist[1].is_eligible:
    [...]
elif mylist[2].skill == 'java' and mylist[2].is_eligible:
    [...]
```

So notice here that I'm using the `elif` statement and the conditions in the pseudocode above shouldn't occur at once, but only one of them should be executed.

If that wasn't the case, I would just loop on every instance in the list and check the condition easily.

Keep in mind that the number of conditions is equal to the length of the list so it doesn't have to be always equal to 3.

### NOTE :

I need to check that condition for the first item , if it's False, I would check it for the second item of the list, if it's True I would stop executing the block of code, and so on ..

Comment: You can use `break` once you find the item that matches

Comment: Well i deleted my answer since i dont want to get down voted, but it would always evaluate the first occurrence and if it's True continue otherwise take the next and so on.
`if [x.skill == 'java' and x.is_eligible for x in mylist]:`

Comment: @user56700 Well, that's what I need, you can rewrite a good answer implementing that now !

Comment: @user56700 - that calculates the list of all answers, not just the first one, and doesn't even keep it for use inside the `if` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `break` once you find the item that matches:

```
for item in mylist:
  if item.skill == 'java' and item.is_eligible:
    print(item)
    break
else:
  print('No match')
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but you didn't understand me, I need to check that condition for the first item , if it's False, I would check it for the second item of the list and so on ..

Comment: Yes, that's what this does; the `break` exits the loop after it's found one that matches

Comment: If you also need the numeric position within the list, use @martineau's variant with `enumerate()`

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
class Instance1: skill = 'java'; is_eligible = False
class Instance2: skill = 'java'; is_eligible = True
class Instance3: skill = 'python'; is_eligible = True


mylist = [Instance1(), Instance2(), Instance3()]

for i, instance in enumerate(mylist):
    if instance.skill == 'java' and instance.is_eligible:
        print(f'mylist[{i}] matched')
        break
else:
    print('none matched')
```